# Show it's a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be set and $d:X \times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and I have to two 2 properties
$$\tag{A1}d(x,y)=0 \leftrightarrow x=y$$
$$\tag{A2}d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+ d(y,z)$$ for all x,y,z in X

If we show the symmetry we can also change A2 such that the triangle inequaltiy is also given.

Now Let's use A2 for symmetry: $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z)$
and $d(y,x)\leq d(y,z)+ d(x,z)$ so we see that $d(x,y)$ and $d(y,x) $ have the same estimates. But what enables me NOW to say that $d(x,y) = d(y,x)$?, it has to be axiomatic when $a \leq c; b\leq c $ then $a=b$ I could not show this.

I have made small mistakes, now its corrected

Thanks for the answer, I will post the longer version here as well.

$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(y,z) $ now use $z=x$ and you have $d(x,y)\leq 0+d(y,x)$
Second part:
$d(y,x) \leq d(y,z)+d(x,z) $ now use $z=y$ and you have $d(x,y)\leq 0+d(x,y)$

so you have: $d(x,y)\leq d(y,x)\&d(y,x)\leq d(x,y)$ at the end this guives us: $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

Comment: You can't. Simmetry is not a consequence of these two axioms. You can construct a simple counterexample with a set with two elements. Say $X=\{ a,b \}$ with $d(a,b)=2$ and $d(b,a)=3$. This satisfies axioms A1 and A2, but it's not symmetric.

Comment: The textbook said it is a metric, i only have to show the symmetry. You need to have a third element aas well

Comment: "If we show the symmetry we can also change A2 such that the triangle inequaltiy is also given." yes because then $d(y,z)=d(z,y)$

Comment: but you can't prove the symmetry from A1 and A2 as @Crostul said, you probably didn't understand what the textbook was saying

Comment: @Laassilasouhayl youre tight my question was regarding the estimates, because i have to show that d(x,y) = d(y,z) following from the estimate

Comment: alright looks like I am wrong

Comment: @Crostul You are wrong. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Crostul That's not a counterexample. Put $x=b$, $y=a$, $z=b$, then $d(x,y) = 3 \not\leq d(x,z) + d(y,z) = 0 + 2$.

Comment: Btw, the problem is slightly incomplete as stated: you of course also need $d(x,y) \geq 0$ for all $x,y$ in order for $d$ to be a metric. But that's not needed in order to conclude symmetry from $A1$ and $A2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put $z=x$ to get $d(x,y) \leq 0+d(y,x)$. Now interchange $x$ and $y$ for the reverse inequlity.

Comment: I believe thats the answer, thank

Comment: I see where my mistake was. Good argument! +1